# Timer isn't working correctly in my code

Tags: java, swing, timer

So the plan of the program I am making is to have an object move from one point to another. The catch is the path is drawn. I am able to draw and place a `shape` to move through the path from start to finish. The problem I am having is that the object is appearing at the end of the path. Even with `timer` set at the end of the `for loop`. All it does is simply wait for the `timer` to finish then the shape is at the end of the path.

I've gone through the code, even printed out each point that has been stored and I am getting points, not just the last point. The object's path is based on a for loop going through each point and placing the object at said point. It's crude atm and uses absolute position (just for the object).

What am I missing?

Here's the code:

```
    JButton add = new JButton("add");
    add(add);
    //new Timer(50, updateTask).start();
    updateTask = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            repaint();  // Refresh the JFrame, callback paintComponent()
        }
     };

    add.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            for (int i = 0; i < path.size(); i++) {
                update(i);   // update the (x, y) position
                new Timer(1000, updateTask).start();
            }
        }
    });
}

public void update(int i) {
    if (released == 1) {
        Point p = path.get(i);
        System.out.println("position at: " + (int) p.getX() + " " + (int) p.getY());
        xPos = (int) p.getX();
        yPos = (int) p.getY();
        System.out.println(i);
    } 
}
```

Comment: You're missing a valid [mcve] -- a small compilable and runnable program that we can compile and run, that illustrates your problem for us and that is (again) very small. Please edit your question and post this code here as code-formatted text with your question.

Comment: Also, I worry when I see a Timer do nothing but call `repaint()` as this suggests that the program has state-modifying code within a painting method, something that shouldn't be.

Comment: Your code loops from 0 to `path.size()`, each time calling `update(i)` and starting a new Timer. It does however never wait for a timer event, so the loop will complete within some milliseconds.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels the update is the only thing that needs to be modified, if all i'm doing is changing the location of the shape. The only place to change the location would be to repaint with the new x and y coordinates right?

Comment: @ThomasKläger how would I make it work? I've been reading up on how timers work and downloaded a couple examples and I still can't really wrap my head around it.

Comment: `new Timer(1000, updateTask).start();` should **probably** be outside the loop. For anything better than 'probably', post an MCVE as suggested by @HovercraftFullOfEels an hour ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't write your loop within an `ActionListener`, since that would block the EventDispatchThread (EDT) and therefore block your UI.

Instead you can use the `updateTask` ActionListener to step through your path each time it is called from the `Timer`:

```
final Timer timer = new Timer(1000, null);
updateTask = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        if (pathIndex < path.size()) {
            update(pathIndex++);
        } else {
            timer.stop();
        }
        repaint();  // Refresh the JFrame, callback paintComponent()
    }
};
timer.addActionListener(updateTask);

add.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        pathIndex = 0;
        timer.start();
    }
});
```

For this to work your class needs an additional int field `pathIndex`

Comment: Thank you so much!! So the way the timer works is that it's kind of loop where it keeps doing it's thing with the intervals given until a statement is met. Did I wrap my head around that properly?

Comment: The timer keeps calling the ActionListeners that you register with the specified intervalls until it is stopped (or the program terminates).